# How to authenticate users?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, file-encryption

I'm in the scenario that I'm planning a detailed description on "how to securely encrypt files" without putting too much in one Q/A.

**So, in a file-encryption scenario, what are the possible ways to authenticate the user?**

Please note that I don't want descriptions on how to perform this on a low level, but rather have a list of high-level approaches to accomplish the above objective.
And please also note that I don't want to rely on "simple" access control checks made in software but rather have something that can be used to derive / transform the file-encryption-key (but not the description on how to do these derivations and transformations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a *few* ways to do this.

You can come down to the following statement:

**For authentication you can only use something the user knows, has or is.**

As you're in a file-encryption scenario, this should rule out most points concerning "what a user is", because they involve biometrical data, which needs to have tolerances.

- A **password or passphrase**. This is the classical way of authenticating users in this scenario, is widely deployed, well accepted and can provide high levels of security. Please note that PINs also fall into this category. From the above sentence this is "something the user knows".
- A **(symmetric) keyfile**, this is something the user has and is usually implemented as an arbitrary file the user can select or generate and which is strongly required for the key-derivation. This is also widely implemented (most better encryption tools use this). Please note that the keyfile may rest on local memory or on a secured device (i.e. a smartcard or HSM).
- An **(asymmetric) key(file)**, this is something the user has as well. Please note the difference to the above keyfile, as this usually isn't input to the key-derivation function directly but used for asymmetric decryption on the user's CPU, smartcard or HSM.
- **Data stored in the OS**. Usually the OS has some way to store data protected and this mechanisms can be used for authentication. Some OS offer secure key storage and some offer encryption of data using the user's credentials. (category: has (PC/OS) / know (credentials))
- **Cryptographic hardware** (smartcards, HSMs, TPMs,...) can be used to securely seal and store keys and integrated cryptographic processors can be used to perform symmetric key transformations (using the stored key), needed for key-derivation. (category: has (hw) / know(PIN))
- **Custom hardware** is probably the most secure way. This hardware can function as the above crypto hardware concerning usage, but authentication can be made highly different than with a standard PIN / password. For example if the hardware is highly trusted (tamper-evident / tamper-resistant) it may be possible to securely implement **biometric authentication** for the device unlock and hence indirectly for the key derivation (as the crypto processor only operates after valid authentication and it's not software access control but hardware access control). Biometric authentication may include but doesn't have to be restricted to voice recognition, fingerprint sensoring, face recognition, DNA testing, brain-activity recognition, iris scanning and hand scanning.

Comment: I'll happily incorporate any approaches I've missed into this answer and I highly ask for more approaches and if I'm inactive for a longer period, it is absolutely asked (by me) to add newer and more approaches.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a community wiki.